# iOS Document Directory files are not retained

Tags: ios, ios5, itunes-app

As per Apple Documentation,

> When a user downloads an app update, iTunes installs the update in a
>   new app directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old
>   installation over to the new app directory before deleting the old
>   installation. Files in the following directories are guaranteed to be
>   preserved during the update process:
>
> /Documents /Library Although files
>   in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely
>   on them being present after an update.

But I am developing an application, and using iTunes for installing the application, all the existing images and files are getting removed on synching device with iTunes.

Also while synching app with iTunes, it is showing Copying ${PROJECT_NAME} in device, whereas it should be updating.

So, if the user is updating any application from AppStore in Mac machine, and is synching the device, will all the records saved in Document Directory for all applications will be removed and user will require to save them again.

Comment: Does your updated app still have the same bundle id of the existing app? This is critical.

Comment: Yes. And the same app I have tested on Simulator, there it retains the files.

Comment: I have also tried to change bundle version with a thought that, it could be happened, because of same bundle version it is copying, but nopes, it is copying in case of upper version, instead of updating the build. The main part is, I am currently using Titanium, where DB file is getting installed in Library/Private Folder. and the records in that DB is retained.